# for loop only looping once

Tags: javascript, loops

My question is concerning a `for` loop that appears to be looping only once and I'm not sure why.

I'm writing a function that compares the last letter of an array element to the first letter of the next array element.

My test input is the array: ["Buddy Bear","Romeo", "Olive"]. These all fit the criteria (the last letter matching the first letter of next) and should be pushed into an array.

I've read all the posts on the subject but couldn't find one that seems to fit my problem. I know I'm missing something simple, just can't see it.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qwL8hq3j/

```
function validName(array){
var lower = []
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    lower.push(array[i].toLowerCase());
} 
var testA = []
var count = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < lower.length; i++) {
    var j = 1;
    if(lower[i].charAt(lower[i].length-1) === lower[j].charAt(0)){
        testA.push(lower[i]);
        j = j + 1;
        count = count + 1;
    } 
  } 
  return count;
}
```

I put a counter in to make sure the code was cycling and it returns 1, making me conclude that it is only looping through a single time. I've also tried to reconfigure the code a few times but I am just not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Don't just give the function in the fiddle. Run the function with a parameter, make it clear what's going wrong.

Comment: Do you have an input and expected output we can see?

Comment: Are you sure that `lower` is being populated?

Comment: Line 3 has 'let' in place of 'var'. If I fix that your code works for me.

Comment: @ Spencer Thanks, sorry first time using fiddle. Wasn't sure of the protocol.

Comment: @JonSG I am entering the array ["Buddy Bear","Romeo", "Olive"] and expecting an output of the counter to go to 3 and all three elements being pushed into the testA array.

Comment: @StephenNelson thanks for the catch, I made the change, but am still only looping through once when I enter an array of three elements.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, when I enter the array input ["Buddy Bear","Romeo", "Olive"] my test array gets pushed "buddy bear", but not the other two elements.

Comment: ["Buddy Bear","Romeo", "Olive"]. These all fit the criteria (the last letter matching the first letter of next) and should be pushed into an array.  **With this requirement, why would "Olive" be part of the output?**

Comment: Works for me...You also have ES2015 code mixed with ES5.  Thus duplicate 'i' variables with different declarations.

Comment: @JonSG this is where I might be going wrong with my code (or my wording is incorrect in my explanation), the O in Olive matches the last "o" in Romeo, therefore Olive should be pushed. If I added another string to the input, say "Jack", the "J" does not back the last "e" in Olive and therefore should not be pushed. My main problem right now is I just don't understand why the loop is stopping at one loop.

Comment: @ryanlutgen thanks for point that out, still trying to learn ES2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = ["heehjko", "oient", "ana", "inm", "mii", "dgdgdfg", "Dove"]

var lower = []
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    lower.push(array[i].toLowerCase());
}
console.log(lower)
var testA = []
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < lower.length; i++) {
    var j = 1;
    console.log(lower[i].charAt(lower[i].length - 1))
    console.log(lower[i + 1])
    if (lower[i + 1] != undefined) {
        if (lower[i].charAt(lower[i].length - 1) === lower[i + 1].charAt(0)) {

            testA.push(lower[i + 1]);
        }
    }

}
console.log(testA)
```

Comment: @gayathir Thank you, as Enamul Haque pointed out in a different answer, the loop is looping properly, (if I understand correctly) it just wasn't pushing properly. Adding the "if (lower[i + 1] != undefined)" made it work perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: happy coding @Matthew Daly

Comment: I do not believe this produces the desired result.  Given **[ "Jane", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob" ]**, I believe the expected result is **[ "Bob", "Bob", "Bob" ]** not **[ "Bob", "Bob" ]**

Comment: (the last letter matching the first letter of next) and should be pushed into an array this is the question please read cleary from Jane the ending letter is e but the next letter is Bob so it wont push in to an array

Comment: @gayathri, You have jumped to the same conclusion as I originally did.  It is you who needs to read more clearly.  The original poster has given this specific example: Given **["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"]** Expect **["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"]**.  This is not the result your answer produces.

Comment: ["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"] FOR THIS THE EXPECTED RESULT SHOULD BE [ "Romeo", "Olive"] , how come you can expect the result ["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"] Buddy Bear is a single word ends with R so Romeo and Romeo ends with O so Olive so the result is  [ "Romeo", "Olive"]

Comment: @gayathri  I expect it because that is what the original poster has given as an example use case.  Read the question and comments attached to the question again.  Quote : *I am entering the array ["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"] and expecting an output of the counter to go to 3 and **all three elements** being pushed into the testA array.*.  Quote : *[my problem is] I enter the array input ["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"] my test array gets pushed **"buddy bear", but not the other two elements**.*  This **is** the required output per the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on additional conversations, the updated requirements seem to be:

> Given an array of names e.g. **[ "Bob", "Jane", ... ]**, traverse the array comparing the last letter of element **n** to the first letter of element **n+1**.  If they match (case insensitive) both elements should be added to a second "results array".  No element (by index) should be added to the results array twice, though duplicate values may exist in the results array.
>
> Use Case A:
>
> Given: **["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"]**
>
> Expect: **["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"]**
>
> Use Case B:
>
> Given: **[ "Jane", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob" ]**
>
> Expect: **[ "Bob", "Bob", "Bob" ]**

```js
function validName(nameList){
  
  function _reducer(acc, item, index, arr){
    var nextIndex = index + 1;
    var nextItem = arr[nextIndex];
    if (!nextItem){ return acc; }

    var charA = item.charAt(item.length -1).toLowerCase();
    var charB = nextItem.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    if (charA !== charB){ return acc; }

    // -------------------
    // Add "item" to the accumulator if it was not already
    // added in the previous itteration as "nextItem".
    // -------------------
    if (acc[acc.length -1] !== index){ acc.push(index); }
    // -------------------

    // -------------------
    // Add "nextItem" to the accumulator.
    // -------------------
    acc.push(nextIndex);
    // -------------------

    return acc;
  } 

  // -------------------
  // Convert the array of indices into an array of values
  // -------------------
  function _mapper(item){ return nameList[item]; }
  // -------------------
  
  var result = nameList.reduce(_reducer, []).map(_mapper);
  return result;
}

var nameList = ["Buddy Bear", "Romeo", "Olive"];
var result = validName(nameList);
console.log("CASE A: ");
console.log("Given: ");
console.log(nameList);
console.log("Result Count = " + result.length);
console.log(result);

console.log("");
console.log("");

nameList = ["Jane", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob"];
result = validName(nameList);
console.log("CASE B: ");
console.log("Given: ");
console.log(nameList);
console.log("Result Count = " + result.length);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you for your excellent code example. I am going to re-edit my question so that it is clearer.

Comment: @MatthewDaly, I added some documentation and updated the code to produce what I believe is the answer you expect. Given **[ "Jane", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob" ]**, expect **[ "Bob", "Bob", "Bob" ]**.  Just a heads up, the answer you have accepted does not produce the correct result.

Comment: I see what you're saying completely, you and gayathri  are working on a higher level than me. Give me a chance to review both answers. (I have to keep in mind that my original question was why my for loop was not looping correctly, hence anybody searching for a similar problem...) Again, it may come down to me incorrectly explaining my goals. Give me a chance to think this through, as I do want the most appropriate solution to be tagged.

Comment: I'm not fishing for rep :-)  Just wanted you to be aware that the other post might not be exactly what you were after.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

## Your code is absolutely Ok

Loop is not looping 1 time. It looping as lower.length and lower.length is 3.
Your if condition

```
if(lower[i].charAt(lower[i].length-1) === lower[j].charAt(0))
```

is get true one time. So that your counter value return 1.If set the counter outside of if condition you will see it

```
for(var i = 0; i < lower.length; i++) {
var j = 1;
if(lower[i].charAt(lower[i].length-1) === lower[j].charAt(0)){
    testA.push(lower[i]);
    j = j + 1;

} 
count = count + 1;
} 
return count;
```

Comment: Perfect! The loop is looping properly, it is in my "if - push" code is where the problem lies. It is only pushing the first string in my array, but it is looping. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work fine with me:

```
function validName(array){
  var result=[],lower=[],count=0,len=0;
  for(i in array){
    lower.push(array[i].toLowerCase());
  }
  for(j in lower){
    i=j;i++;if(j==lower.length-1){break;}
    len=lower[j].length-1;
    var u=lower[j].charAt(len);
    var l=lower[i].charAt(0);
    if(u==l){
       result.push(lower[j]);
       count++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
alert(validName(["Buddy Bear","Romeo", "Olive"]));
```

Answer (score -1):

First, add ";" at the end of command

```
var lower = []
```

↓↓↓

```
var lower = [];
```

Second, assign result into array, then return.

```
for(var i = 0; i < lower.length; i++) {
  ...
  arr_result.push(count);
}
return arr_result;
```

Hope it helps.